# Flutter - Wrap column around image

Tags: flutter, dart, word-wrap

I just want to know if in Flutter it's possible to wrap a entire column around my image like this:

[image: 1]

I found [DropCrapText](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text) but I only can wrap a text with a child (image in my case).

```
Container(
    child: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Image.network(
      'https://www.codemate.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/flutter-logo.png',
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("BIG TITLE", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
          Text("Little subtitle", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
          Text(
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Thank you

Comment: do you have some code you can share with us?

Comment: It may be possible with a WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is now possible, like this:

```
import 'package:float_column/float_column.dart';

FloatColumn(
  children: const [
    Floatable(
      float: FCFloat.start,
      maxWidthPercentage: 0.25,
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 12),
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 100),
    ),
    WrappableText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: 'BIG TITLE',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
    WrappableText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: 'Little subtitle',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
    WrappableText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text:
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sed erat efficitur, tincidunt purus ut, fermentum erat. Morbi vitae nulla lorem. Ut ac velit tempus, semper ante quis, iaculis nibh. Suspendisse potenti.')),
  ],
)
```

Which will look like this:
[image]